# event stopPropagation doesn't stop propagation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, content-script, browser-extension

I am working on a chrome extension where I created a [context script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/) on a [Notion](https://www.notion.so/) Page.

If user is focused on an input inside context script and hits backspace/delete, character in input is deleted with a content on a Notion page. I fixed this issue by adding `onKeyDown` handler:

```
export const onKeyDown = (evt: React.KeyboardEvent) => {
  if (evt.key === 'Backspace') {
    evt.stopPropagation()
  }
}
```

Now, If user is focused on an input inside context script and hits backspace/delete, only input value is removed.

I came across another issue when it's not possible to paste text into input by pressing Ctrl+V or Cmd+V. When user is focused on an input inside context script and press Ctrl+V or Cmd+V, the text is pasted into Notion page instead of focused input. I tried to fix this by adding:

```
export const onKeyDownDefault = (evt: React.KeyboardEvent) => {
  if (evt.key === 'Backspace') {
    evt.stopPropagation()
  }
  // Ctrl+V or Cmd+V pressed?
  if ((evt.ctrlKey || evt.metaKey) && evt.keyCode == 86) {
    console.log('stop propagate')
    evt.stopPropagation()
    // evt.preventDefault()
  }
}
```

But it didn't help. I can see the console output 'stop propagate', but the text is not pasted into input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because Notion is listeniing to the `paste` event instead, try to also `stopPropagation` for the `paste` event instead.

Working example:

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
<script>
  document.addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
    console.log((event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text'));
  });
  const elInput = document.getElementById('input');
  elInput.addEventListener('keydown', (ev) => ev.stopPropagation());
  elInput.addEventListener('paste', (ev) => ev.stopPropagation());
</script>
```

Non-working example:

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
<script>
  document.addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
    console.log((event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text'));
  });
  const elInput = document.getElementById('input');
  elInput.addEventListener('keydown', (ev) => ev.stopPropagation());
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about paste event!